# Xamarin.Forms - Create app shortcut in Android and iOS device

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm new in Xamarin.Forms and I developed a cross-application to use only on my Android device and Apple iPad using Visual Studio 2019.

So, trying first to Android, I created the .APK file using "Ad Hoc" option. But, when I install the application on my mobile device, no shortcut was created on the Android screen.

I serched a lot on the Internet without success how to create a shortcuts on Android and/or iOS devices in the installation process.

Can anyone help me how to do this? I appreciate if a tutorial is sent.

Sorry for my poor English.

Regards,

Marcelo Camarate

Answer (score 0):

1. Change Debug to Release.
2. Right-click your xxx.Android file and select Archive.
3. Select Distribute in the lower right corner.
4. Choose Ad Hoc.
5. Click the plus icon to create the certificate.
6. Select Save As to save your apk file to your computer.
7. Move the file to your phone and click install.

According to my test, the above method can work successfully, and the shortcut is successfully generated.